# Venn diagram question has too many variables to be solvable

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

I've looked at a few of the similar ones - but they're not quite the same, and when I used the same methods - I'm getting an unsolvable equation.

> In a class of 30 students, 5 study no languages at all, 9 study French, 14 study Japanese, and 15 study Korean. If 5 students study French and Japanese, and 3 students study French and Korean, what is the probability that student chosen at random studies all 3 languages?

For clarification, the 5 students who study French and Japanese can also include students who study French, Japanese and Korean.

This is the Venn diagram I've made and also the equations I've set up.

[image]

We know that the total participants must be 25 and this is equal to if we sum all the unique spaces of the Venn Diagram:
$$25 = \color{black} {9-a-b-c} + \color{red} {a+b+c} + \color{orange} {14-a-b-d} + \color{red} d + \color{blue} {15-a-c-d}$$
$$13 = 2a + b+ d+c (\text{Eqn 1})$$

We are also told that the total number of people doing French and Japanese is 5 so: $5=a+b$ and the total number of people doing French and Korean is 3 so: $3=a+c$. We can thus solve simultaneously using these 2 and Eqn 1 and get: $d=5$.

But from there, all the equations I've set up lead in circles. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: "For clarification, the 5 students who study French and Japanese can also include students who study French, Japanese and Korean." Is this clarification yours, or the book's ? Can you reproduce the **exact** wording of the question ?

Comment: The exact wording is given in the question. I've given the clarification based on looking at the answers. If you assume it means "5 students studying French and Japanese and NOT Korean" then the answer doesn't work when you sub it back in (answer = 1/15 chance)

Comment: I agree with your assessment--consistent with the information given, the value of $a$ could be anything between 0 and 3.

Comment: What you are missing is that the question is about probability, not set theory. You are trying to figure out the exact number of students speaking all three languages, but there are seven unknowns but only six equations, so there is not enough information to solve it that way. But probability usually involves situations where there is not full information, so this is not unique. Try approaching it as a question about probability right from the start, not as some tack-on only to be considered at the end.